# Can we use FHIR to define a service route?

Tags: hl7-fhir

Is there a way to define a service route in FHIR? We need to define a semi-static route where services are delivered on a routine basis. This is largely for meal deliveries, but could include other services as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use List to define an ordered list of delivery Locations, however that's not going to give you driving directions to navigate.  If you need a true 'route' with directions, way-points, times, etc., you'll need extensions.

Comment: Lloyd, I always appreciate your insights on FHIR. Any FHIR courses you'd recommend?

Comment: That's a hard question to answer.  In part, it depends what you want to learn.  I think my courses are good, but I've never been on the receiving end of them - and I'm not a neutral observer :)  And I don't take most other people's courses.  My own primary sources of learning are paying close attention to http://chat.fhir.org and DevDays.  (The videos are made freely available after 6 months and are a goldmine of useful content.)  Oh, and I guess reading the specs in detail too :)